# Search with exclusion (MUSTNOT) in children fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to find all cities which are not contain term "big" in the name of the street.

Here is my items in index:

```
{
  "name":"the big street",
  "city": "NY",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "name":"not big street",
  "city": "AM",
  "count": 43
},
{
  "name":"st42",
  "city": "NY",
  "count": 1687
},
{
  "name":"Anacostia Drive",
  "city": "WASH",
  "count": 1687
},
```

I need to find all *cities* where name MUST NOT contains (exclude) the term "big".

when I try to use term query with must_not

```
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "city"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
"must_not" : {
        "term" : {
          "name" : { "big" }
        }
      },
    }
 }
}
```

I found   cities includes "NY",  due item with "st42" - and it's wrong due match with "the big street" item.

How to resolve it?

Decision below it good, but query can be more complicated and I need highlight:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_by_city": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city.keyword",
        "size": 20
      },
      "aggs": {

        "filter_exclude_count": {
          "filter": { "match" : { "name" : "big"   }}
        },
        "filter_include_count": {
          "filter": { "match" : { "name" : "Anacostia"   }}
        },
        "selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "exclude_cnt": "filter_exclude_count._count",
              "include_name": "filter_include_count._count"
            },
            "script": "params.exclude_cnt == 0 && params.include_name > 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to "find all the cities which does not have any street which has "big" in street name"?

You can do it using `aggregation`, this solution does not use `collapse`:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_by_city": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter_exclude_count": {
          "filter": { "match" : { "street" : "big"   }}
        },
        "sellector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "exclude_cnt": "filter_exclude_count._count"
            },
            "script": "params.exclude_cnt == 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

1. Group all city
2. Count all documents which street name contains "big"
3. If the above count == 0 then select this `aggs_by_city` aggregation using [bucket_selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

Comment: I want to find all cities which are  not contain term "big" in the name of the street.

Comment: @ArkadySpiridonov I updated the solution, but I'm using aggregation

Comment: Thank you! How do you think, maybe it's better to change index structure with nested fields?
city : [streets: {"name": "big",{ "name":"not big" }] - something like this. no?

Comment: How you structure your field really depend on how you want to query data? Do you mean multi-fields with previous document? Also can you show me how you would query the above document?

Comment: The problems is that I need highlights for my results, like this: 
"filter_exclude_count": {
          "filter": { "match" : { "name" : "big"   }}
        },
        "filter_include_count": {
          "filter": { "match" : { "name" : "Anacostia"   }}
        },
        "selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "exclude_cnt": "filter_exclude_count._count",
              "include_name": "filter_include_count._count"
            },
            "script": "params.exclude_cnt == 0 && params.include_name > 0"
          }
        }

Comment: I'jve tested it now - bucket_selector search too slow in big index.

Comment: can you share how many document you get? actually I have not thought about performance very much. I think of one way of doing it which is we store all street in one field (by concat to a big text field) and each document is one city, but we have to change data model of the index

Comment: about 1.5 billion. 
Yes, I think about change structure too. Do you think it will work? 
Something like this

{
  city: {
    name: 'NY'
    streets_names: [
      'the big street not big street'
    ],
    streets: [
      {
        name: 'the big street',
        count: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'not big street',
        count: 18
      }
    ]
  }
}

How do you think?

Comment: yes, it definitively works in this query use case, but you'll have to create new index and reindex all data to new index